# When inserting lkm rootkit the kernel crashes

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cryptography, kernel-module, rootkit

I am writing an lkm rootkit for ubuntu 5.19.0-35-generic 20.04 tls server, found [here](https://github.com/ArtemisesAngel/Aegis-Suite/tree/main/Lelantos). I have a program that updates the hex string of a big int, and whenever I run it the entire kernel crashes.

```
int update_hex(big_int_t *number){
  kfree(number->hex);
  number->hex = kmalloc(number->size, GFP_KERNEL);
  if(!number->hex){
    printk("big_int: error allocating memory for hex\n");
    return -1;
  }
  printk("number is at %p\n", number->number);
  for (int i=0; i<number->size/64; i++){
    char temp[8];
    printk("number part %i: 0x%llx\n", i, number->number[i]);
    sprintf(temp, "%llx", number->number[i]);
    printk("creaated hex- %s\n", temp);
    strcat(number->hex, temp);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
struct big_int_t{
  uint64_t *number;
  int size;
  char *hex;
};
```

whenever I insert the module that uses the function, the kernel crashes. i commented out any use of the function, it works perfectly. the file with the deceleration of the functions is [here](https://github.com/ArtemisesAngel/Aegis-Suite/blob/main/Lelantos/custom/encryption/big_math.h) and the function using with using the library is [here](https://github.com/ArtemisesAngel/Aegis-Suite/blob/main/Lelantos/custom/encryption/encryption.h)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly post all relevant code here. People aren't very likely to follow external links.

Comment: "entire kernel crashes" Do you mean Linux gets crashed and rebooted?

Comment: @Haris, it's just GitHub.

Comment: Wild guess: `char temp[8];` is one byte short of the space needed for a string representation of a 32 bit integer... Buffer too small??

Comment: @Fe2O3 `8` bytes can hold 64-bit integers... Ah, you mean `string representation`, okay, my bad.

Comment: Yep, you are right.

Comment: One more comment: The "string buffer" returned by `malloc()` is uninitialised. Attempting to `strcat()` anything to these random bytes is likely to fail. (PS: Why allocate perhaps 128 bytes to store the 32+1 ASCII characters needed? Also, there's no "leading zeros" in the format specifier. And, integer division is risky for non-PowerOfTwo values...) These seem to me to be unjustifiable junior level mistakes.

Comment: @Fe2O3 More like 9 bytes too short. (It needs space for 16 hex digits and a null terminator.)